# Traveled Distance measurement

Tags: navigation, turtlebot2, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi !

I would like to measure the total distance the Turtlebot traveled while navigating. So I was wondering if there was a way to get this information from the odometry sensors ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66671/traveled-distance-measurement/) by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2013-07-04

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can subscribe to the publication of the pose topic and store each publication in a pose array, for example. Then you can process that array to sum the distances between each reading.

```
float path_length = 0.0;
std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>::iterator it = plan.poses.begin();
geometry_msgs::PoseStamped last_pose;
last_pose = *it;
it++;
for (; it!=plan.poses.end(); ++it) {
   path_length += hypot(  (*it).pose.position.x - last_pose.pose.position.x, 
                         (*it).pose.position.y - last_pose.pose.position.y );
   last_pose = *it;
}
ROS_INFO("... path length: %6.3f", path_length);
```

[source of this code](https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/browser/branches/trunk_cturtle/stacks/point_cloud_perception_experimental/object_mapping/src/move_base_interface.cpp?rev=46496)

you can do the same with the odometry publications, but you may have an accumulated error there.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2013-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-05**:
Yes, I thought about this solution :) But I hoped there was a way to get the data from wheels' odometry and that I just didn't find it. I'll do it like this then. Thanks.

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2013-07-05**:
you can do that, but you will have errors due to slippage, sensors, and others... if you want to try you have to find out what program is publishing the turtlebot odom, because it must access your sensors readings to build the message, so you can get those readings too and try to integrate them.

**Comment by [Wentao](https://answers.ros.org/users/32450/wentao/) on 2017-10-31**:
Hi, I have one question about what you said. I make sense the code you post, but how can calculate it in Matlab environment. Is there any easier way. Thanks.